# Switching to local update server has slowed down my update process

Tags: updates, update-manager, stable-release-updates

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I have just changed the server settings to the server in my country. Since then, my Ubuntu updates have become very slow. Why is this? And how can I speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you use the source server marked as "Main Server". The connection speed to the local server would vary from country to country.

Another possible solution is to choose the "Other" option, then select "Select Best Server". This will make Ubuntu test the connection speed of all the servers and choose the best one.

Lastly, you can select a "First World" server given that they usually have better Internet connection speeds.

Answer (score 0):

you probably changed the location where APT is taking the sources from.

you can change your sources.list located here :  `/etc/apt/sources.list`

an easier way is probably to change the software sources directly in UI of Software Center.

- open software center
- click Edit on top and select software sources
- select server where to take sources from